# Can't catch access violation

Tags: delphi, access-violation, try-except

We have a Delphi app that has been running for a few years and now suddenly we get weird access violations. We used Eurekalog to trace where it comes from and this is even more weird. They are so far all on the Free call of an object, but inside a try except block. One of them is even in 2 try except blocks and still when the Access Violation occurs it jumps totally out of the program and ignores the try excepts, nothing excepts EurekaLog catches it at the end. Really confused on why this is suddenly happening (both instances are old code that has not been touched for years and also other codes changes is not related to it).

A example of the code is

```
      try
    if Assigned(ClientCommunication) then   begin
      if ClientCommunication.isConnected then  begin
        if ClientCommunication.closeServerConnection then   begin
          try
            ClientCommunication.Free;
            ClientCommunication := nil;
          Except
            on e:Exception do begin
             ClientCommunication := nil; //suppress weird AV error.. get read for new object
            end
          end;
```

Now  the last try except was added later to try and suppress the AV as we just want the object cleared to be restarted if required, but this is mostly called when closing the app. But it still just jumps out of that and I can’t catch it at all.

It works on our developers PCs and not at the client.

Comment: Smells like heap corruption. The solution is going to involve debugging. Only you can do that.

Comment: _Heap corruption_ is most likely the case, but I can imagine that the `.closeServerConnection()` method destroys the parent object of the `ClientCommunication` object (trough a callback or some pointer acrobatics) so any attempt to access it could easily lead to an AV error. In either case you could try to debug the problem by adding a watch to `ClientCommunication` AND its parent also, then execute the code line-by-line and look where the pointers got released. **The error is obviously not in the code shown above.**

Comment: I did that type of debugging, problem is the parent actually does not get freed anywhere inside the close. It just sends the close command to the server and close the connection. That why it very weird. But if heap corruption then really weird. Will see what I can do, adding FastMM4 now to try and see if it can help somehow give some light on issue.

Comment: @MartynA Please take a look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202969/how-can-we-encourage-reviewers-to-care-about-spelling

Comment: @Johannes You should try getting a pointer to the parent and `ClientCommunication` (Like `Debug -> Evaluate and modify -> set expression to Pointer(@ClientCommunication`), then add a watch to the pointers and the pointed values. This way You will see exactly where the heap is corrupted or the objects are released (where the pointers or the pointed values change).

Comment: @Johannes Your edit fails to correct all the errors. Try harder please.

Comment: @mg30rg : Thank you will try that. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @David Heffernan - must be honest don't really see most of them as errors as per my normal way of communicating and taking into account that English is not really my language at all I actually do try hard already :)

Comment: The errors are all listed at the meta post. Both in the question and the answer. Your English is excellent.

Comment: @David Heffernan - thank you. Will learn the more I use this I believe.

Comment: Is this a multi-threaded app? Is ClientCommunication being freed in another thread? What's `ClientCommunication.Free` look like? Have you seen `FreeAndNil`?

Comment: @Marcus Adams - No it is not multithreaded. The ClientCommunication.Free frees all the internal objects inside the class used. I have seen FreeandNil yes. It actually also throws he same error (trying to step in to see what is cause with this code). This code did work always worked from 2000 when it was done. But we have new versions out now trying to debug more around it, thank you for all suggestions and help with this.

Comment: @mg30rg - in the IDE on developer machine the object is allocated each time, cant emulate the problem on our machine at all. trying to get a other machine where we can emulate it on and install IDE there if needed and see if we can see what is the cause, but really dumbstruck at moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this line: `ClientCommunication.Free;` is causing an exception.
There are a few things you can do here.

**FreeAndNil**
Replace calls to `AObject.free` with calls to `freeandnil(AObject)`.
If you just do the free, the old pointer will still have a non-nil reference and `Assigned(AObject)` will not be able to tell a freed and active object apart.

**Beware of clones**
Another mistake you may make is that you've cloned the object like so:

```
Object1:= TObject1.Create;
//.... lots of code
Object2:= Object1;
//.... lots of code
FreeAndNil(Object2);  <<-- freeing the clone-reference is a mistake
//.... lots of code
Object1.Free; <<-- exception: it's already freed
```

**FastMM4 options**
Download the latest FastMM4 from  http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/
It has a few extra bells and whistles from the one included with Delphi.(*)
Among those whistles is an extra diagnostic mode that makes your program dead slow, but also catches out a lot of those heap corruption bugs you seem to be suffering from.

Open up `defines.inc` and change this:

```
{$ifdef DEBUG}
  {.$define EnableMemoryLeakReporting}
  {.$define FullDebugMode}
  {.$define RawStackTraces}
{$endif DEBUG}
```

Into this

```
{$ifdef DEBUG}
  {$define EnableMemoryLeakReporting}
  {$define FullDebugMode}
  {$define RawStackTraces}
  {$define CatchUseOfFreedInterfaces}  <<-- very useful
  {$define LogMemoryLeakDetailToFile}
  {$define LogErrorsToFile}
  {$define CheckHeapForCorruption}  <<-- :-) 
{$endif}
```

There's a nice article here: http://wiert.me/2009/07/29/delphi-fastmm-using-fastmm4-for-debugging-your-memory-allocations-part-1-introduction/
If you don't feel like mucking about with the inc file, there a little utility that will do it for you at: http://jedqc.blogspot.com/2007/07/new-fastmm4-options-interface.html

(*) *I think the Delphi one has most of the debug stuff as well, but not 100% sure. Regardless can't hurt to get the latest (greatest) version.*

**Or buffer overflow**
If your `ClientCommunication` object has some internal structure free will do extra work.

Imagine the following code:

```
TUnrelatedObject = class
   buffer: array[0..99] of integer;
   procedure DoWork;
end;

TUnrelatedObject.DoWork;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i:= 0 to 100 do buffer[i]:= maxint;  <<-- buffer overrun
end;
```

Imagine that `ClientCommunication` is right next to `UnrelatedObject` in the heap.
The call to `DoWork` will overwrite data of `ClientCommunication` as well.
This may or may not trigger an access violation in DoWork. If it doesn't then the error will be very hard to trace, because it will show up in a different and totally unrelated places.

Enable range checking `{$R+}` in your application.

**Warning**
Remember to **not** ship the debug version to your clients.
With all the debugging your program will be dead slow.

Comment: Thank you all of this actually helps alot. Stil working on it, but I believe with all this information we will for certain get to the specific spot that is creating our problems. Thank you for your time and effort into this answer.

Comment: just want to say thanks. the settings helped alot and with the more debug information and logging I eventually found the problem with a pointer and it seemed to be the cause for the obscure errors. Now all is running fine again. thank you.